# What is wrong with my switch case code on swift

Tags: swift, switch-statement, case

As you see I am new at coding.

I am trying to print the correct week day on switch case.
But i can't.
What is wrong with my code?

```
var aNumber =  Int.random(in: 0...10)

func dayOfTheWeek(day: Int) {

    switch dayOfTheWeek {

    case ..<2:
        print ("Monday")

    case ..<3:
        print ("Tuesday")

    case ..<4:
        print ("Wednesday")

    case ..<5:
        print ("Thursday")

    case ..<6:
        print ("Friday")

    case ..<7:
        print ("Saturday")

    case ..<8:
        print ("Sunday")

    default:
        print("Error")

    }

    print(aNumber)

}

dayOfTheWeek(day: aNumber)
```

Comment: Hi @muratonurkaya and welcome to StackOverfly! It'd be really helpful if you could also paste the error that you are receiving.

Comment: Not related to your question but the switch it is totally unnecessary. You can simply use Calendar standaloneWeekdaySymbols and return a random element. `let weekday = Calendar.current.standaloneWeekdaySymbols.randomElement()`

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch on the parameter `day` (instead of the function name), and you don't need to match ranges like `..<2` only single numbers:

```swift
switch day {

case 2:
    print ("Monday")

case 3:
    print ("Tuesday")

// and so on...
```

Answer (score 2):

dayOfTheWeek is the function, while day is the Int.
Therefore, you have to switch through the Integer.

Try `switch day {...}`.